# Infinite recursion in PostgreSQL rule

Tags: postgresql

I am inserting large amount of data and I am using EF Core as an ORM, and data may have conflicting primary key from times to times due to concurrency. I am trying to create a rule in PostgresSQL in order to intercept the INSERT call and transform it into an INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING. I have defined a rule, however PostgreSQL complains that it has detected an infinite recursion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE table1_insert_on_conflict_rule AS
ON INSERT TO public.table1
WHERE new.ignore_duplicate_pkey IS TRUE
DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, ignore_duplicate_pkey) 
VALUES (new.id, new.col1, false) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Any ideas on how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Use a trigger instead

Comment: With high concurrency, a trigger based solution could fail. You can rename your table to f.ex. `table1_data` and create a `table1` named view with all the CRUD rules (backed by `table1_data`). Your ORM will never know it's talking to a view, not a "real" table.

Comment: @pozs This did the trick, no self-dependency and no additional column required, thanks! Also, I had to use ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE because the ORM was complaining that it affected 0 rows while it expected to affect 1.  Please write your comment as an answer so it can be marked